# How to exclude all rows in left table if a condition meets in right table without using a subquery oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, subquery, query-optimization

I have two table, BATCH_MESSAGES, BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS and I want to exclude all Batches if any of its instructions' status is either suspended/Rejected.

Here left is BATCH_MESSAGES and BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS is right.

Here is DDL for BATCH_MESSAGES [image: BATCH_MESSAGES]

And this is for: BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS

[image: BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS]

Only 'CDC-SCBP-862411139626' should be output as it's the only one that has all instructions status NOT IN
suspended/Rejected .

My query produces same result **but its complicated and inefficient as it uses a subquery**. Is there a better way to do it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT BM.ID,
         BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE,
         BM.PARENT_BATCH_ID
FROM iris_activity.BATCH_MESSAGES BM 
WHERE BM.INSTRUCTIONS_COUNT = BM.PROCESSED_INSTRUCTIONS
AND BM.STAGE NOT IN ('COMPLETED')
AND BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE NOT LIKE 'pacs.004%'
AND BM.RECEIVING_MODE = 'Stream' 
AND BM.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT BATCH_ID 
                  FROM iris_activity.BATCH_MESSAGES bm 
                  INNER JOIN Iris_activity.BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS bi  
                         on (bm.id = bi.BATCH_ID 
                            and bm.BATCH_MSG_TYPE = bi.BATCH_TYPE)
                   WHERE STATUS IN ('Suspended','Rejected') 
                   GROUP BY BATCH_ID, STATUS)
AND BM.RETRIES              <=5 ;
```

Can this be more efficient and simpler?

Comment: Please include the DDL (you've only shared a few column values from a few rows). How many rows do you really have in these tables? How long does your query actually take? Please share the execution plan so we can see what you're working with. Is `id` the primary key of `batch_messages`? One would expect so but you've added `distinct` to your query, suggesting there would be rows with the same `id`. Using a subquery does not make a query inefficient. Using `group by batch_id, status` and also `distinct batch_id` in the subquery is overkill, the `not in` will implicitly deduplicate this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` instead if `Not in`

```
SELECT DISTINCT BM.ID,
         BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE,
         BM.PARENT_BATCH_ID
FROM iris_activity.BATCH_MESSAGES BM 
WHERE BM.INSTRUCTIONS_COUNT = BM.PROCESSED_INSTRUCTIONS
AND BM.STAGE NOT IN ('COMPLETED')
AND BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE NOT LIKE 'pacs.004%'
AND BM.RECEIVING_MODE = 'Stream' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Iris_activity.BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS bi  
                         WHERE  bm.id = bi.BATCH_ID 
                            and bm.BATCH_MSG_TYPE = bi.BATCH_TYPE
                            and STATUS IN ('Suspended','Rejected') 
                            )
AND BM.RETRIES              <=5 ;
```

Comment: it still doesnt eliminate subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a NOT IN subquery to a left-joined inline view and add a predicate that ensures the value from the inline view IS NULL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT BM.ID,
         BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE,
         BM.PARENT_BATCH_ID
FROM iris_activity.BATCH_MESSAGES BM 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT BATCH_ID 
    FROM iris_activity.BATCH_MESSAGES bm 
    INNER JOIN Iris_activity.BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS bi  
            on (bm.id = bi.BATCH_ID 
           and bm.BATCH_MSG_TYPE = bi.BATCH_TYPE)
    WHERE STATUS IN ('Suspended','Rejected') 
    GROUP BY BATCH_ID, STATUS
) suspended_or_rejected
  on  BM.BM_ID = suspended_or_rejected_batches.BATCH_ID
WHERE BM.INSTRUCTIONS_COUNT = BM.PROCESSED_INSTRUCTIONS
AND BM.STAGE NOT IN ('COMPLETED')
AND BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE NOT LIKE 'pacs.004%'
AND BM.RECEIVING_MODE = 'Stream' 
AND BM.RETRIES              <=5
--New predicate:
AND suspended_or_rejected.BATCH_ID IS NULL;
```

While this change is actually *more* complicated than your original example, this approach is often significantly faster when you are joining a large percentage of rows from two tables. The `LEFT JOIN` is more likely to be able to use a hash join, which may be much faster than a nested loop and index lookup.

But you should also check the execution plan for your original query. Subqueries do not necessarily make a query inefficient since Oracle is often able to rewrite queries and merge the subqueries into the main query.

Comment: Is `GROUP BY BATCH_ID, STATUS` actually required?

Comment: @Popeye You're right, some of those elements can be removed. I was trying to focus on the left join/is null trick and not make any other changes. Your approach is probably a faster way to run this query, but I'm not sure if you can apply some of the same conditions to both the inclusion and the exclusion sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function `COUNT` with few rewrites in your query as follows:

```
Select DISTINCT BM.ID,
       BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE,
       BM.PARENT_BATCH_ID
  From
    (SELECT BM.*,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN BI.STATUS IN ('Suspended','Rejected') THEN 1 END) 
                  Over(partition by BM.ID) AS CNT -- analytical function
       FROM iris_activity.BATCH_MESSAGES BM 
       LEFT JOIN Iris_activity.BATCH_INSTRUCTIONS bi
         ON bm.id = bi.BATCH_ID and bm.BATCH_MSG_TYPE = bi.BATCH_TYPE
      WHERE BM.INSTRUCTIONS_COUNT = BM.PROCESSED_INSTRUCTIONS
        AND BM.STAGE NOT IN ('COMPLETED')
        AND BM.BATCH_MSG_TYPE NOT LIKE 'pacs.004%'
        AND BM.RECEIVING_MODE = 'Stream' 
        AND BM.RETRIES <= 5            
    ) BM
 WHERE BM.CNT = 0 -- this condition
```